# IT Ticket Helpdesk Support Software

Tags: monitoring, help-desk, support-tracker

I am looking for an IT ticket/Help Desk tracking software so I can have my customers create technology tickets they are having and I could track them, respond and fix the issue.

I found this post but it is over 8 years old. Support Ticketing system

I will be installing it on a Windows 2012 Server which runs Plesk 17.x. I am looking for something that would allow me to customize fields, add additional fields/questions and is well versed for IT issues. I would like it also to be able to send new tickets to my phone either by text or email. For now I will be the only one administering it. Any suggestions on something affordable, good and why? Thanks!

Comment: "I found this post" What post?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Bugzilla](https://www.bugzilla.org/)?  A good old reliable system, and I know it does send notification emails

Comment: Looking into it now. Does this only work for tracking bugs in software? I'm looking more for a ticket tracking system for IT services. For example if a customers printer isn't working they can login and create a ticket to notify our IT team so someone can track and fix the printer issue. Not sure if this would work for this situation!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Jitbit Helpdesk Ticketing system](https://www.jitbit.com/helpdesk/)? Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers so I'm not posting any reviews/pros/cons since I'm obviously biased.

But since you mentioned you need a **self-hosted** app for a **Windows** server it seems like a perfect fit. It's basically the only self-hosted helpdesk app for MS stack (.NET based)

Answer (score 0):

[Spiceworks](https://www.spiceworks.com/) has both a cloud based and self hosted option. It is free to use.